# How to make the icon's border-right not round but straight

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

In the project I use material-ui. Added icons to the header. And the first two of them need to add border-right. Now the problem is that it is round, as in the picture below, and I need a straight border. How can i do this?

[image]

```js
          <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 0 }}>
            <Tooltip title="Favorites">
              <IconButton sx={{ p: 2, borderRight: 1 }}>
                <FavoriteIcon alt="Favorite" />
              </IconButton>
            </Tooltip>
            <Tooltip title="My Profile">
              <IconButton sx={{ p: 2, borderRight: 1 }}>
                <PersonIcon alt="Profile" />
              </IconButton>
            </Tooltip>
            <Tooltip title="Notifications">
              <IconButton sx={{ p: 2 }}>
                <NotificationsIcon alt="Notifications" />
              </IconButton>
            </Tooltip>
          </Box>
```

Comment: Wrap them into a `div` and apply your `border-right` on this `div`

Comment: When I use a div as a wrapper, styles are required and the three icons are not in the same row. Is it possible to do this without the div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need a line between each of the buttons, take a look at the [Divider](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-divider/) component from MUI.

```
  <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 0 }}>
    <Tooltip title="Favorites">
      <IconButton sx={{ p: 2, borderRight: 1 }}>
        <FavoriteIcon alt="Favorite" />
      </IconButton>
    </Tooltip>
    <Divider orientation="vertical" flexItem />
    <Tooltip title="My Profile">
      <IconButton sx={{ p: 2, borderRight: 1 }}>
        <PersonIcon alt="Profile" />
      </IconButton>
    </Tooltip>
    <Divider orientation="vertical" flexItem />
    <Tooltip title="Notifications">
      <IconButton sx={{ p: 2 }}>
        <NotificationsIcon alt="Notifications" />
      </IconButton>
    </Tooltip>
  </Box>
```